# Error while trying to capture artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, devops

I have been tasked with capturing artifacts in the build process of a Jenkin's build.  It is a multi-stage pipeline and I have added, as the last stage, a stage to hopefully accomplish this.  I am fairly new to Jenkin's so this may be an obvious error / mistake to more advances users out there.

```
stage('collect and upload kickstart artifact') {
  steps {
    def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID

    def uploadSpec = """{
      "files": [
        {
           "pattern": "ks/*.cfg",
           "target": "bin-local-cei/ks/"
        },
      ]
    }"""
    server.upload(uploadSpec)

    def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
    buildInfo.env.capture = true
    buildInfo.env.collect()
    buildInfo=server.upload(uploadSpec)
    server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
  }
}
```

**I am getting the following errors** ...

```
WorkflowScript: 117: Expected a step @ line 117, column 9.
           def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID
           ^

WorkflowScript: 119: Expected a step @ line 119, column 9.
           def uploadSpec = """{
           ^

WorkflowScript: 127: Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks. @ line 127, column 9.
           server.upload(uploadSpec)
           ^

WorkflowScript: 129: Expected a step @ line 129, column 9.
           def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
           ^

WorkflowScript: 130: Expected a step @ line 130, column 9.
           buildInfo.env.capture = true
           ^

WorkflowScript: 131: Expected a symbol @ line 131, column 9.
           buildInfo.env.collect()
           ^

WorkflowScript: 132: Expected a step @ line 132, column 9.
           buildInfo=server.upload(uploadSpec)
           ^

WorkflowScript: 133: Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks. @ line 133, column 9.
           server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
           ^

WorkflowScript: 131: Missing required parameter: "message" @ line 131, column 9.
           buildInfo.env.collect()
           ^
```

9 errors

I've dug through blogs, posts, and articles but I am missing something here.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some definitions like, `node` and `script`
I'm just not sure if the `Artifactory` will work, because I dont have this plugin installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('collect and upload kickstart artifact') {
      steps {
        node('master') {
          script {
            def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID

            def uploadSpec = """{
              "files": [
                {
                   "pattern": "ks/*.cfg",
                   "target": "bin-local-cei/ks/"
                },
              ]
            }"""
            server.upload(uploadSpec)

            def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
            buildInfo.env.capture = true
            buildInfo.env.collect()
            buildInfo=server.upload(uploadSpec)
            server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cpanato, thanks.  I have an agent block at the beginning of the Jenkinsfile, agent {
    node {
      label 'packer'
    }
  }
I have not tried the node as well as the script blocks yet but I can do that if you think it might help!

Comment: Since I had the agent block already defining the node info at the beginning of the Jenkinsfile, I added the script block just like you did above, but right underneath 'steps {'  That worked!  I ran into another issue something dealing with a folder location and the fact it already exists.  I'm looking into that now.